# How to add a check box to a simple product?

Tags: magento-1.7

I was looking for the similar questions, but did not find any that carried a similar goal.

My goal is add a check box that will appear on each product page from one category, that has simple products only. Before a customer will be able to click on BUY s/he will have to pick option1 or option2 from this box. This option has to appear in the information about the order.

This should not turn a simple product into a configurable product.

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom options for simple products and display them in the category page:

http://hkpatel201.blogspot.com.es/2012/09/get-product-custom-option-in-list-page.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it did not completely answer my question as I did not know how to phrase it. But using your answer I found the answer [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfZCXjWqrSM)

Comment: Is there a way to apply custom option to all products within a category?

Comment: You can follow this answer : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32021/how-to-add-customization-option-for-each-product-in-magento/32026#32026 . In the collection you must filter with category_id for apply only products inside it

Comment: Do I have to change

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach($products as $product)

TO

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection(category_id=MyCategoryId);
foreach($products as $product) {

Or do I have to change something different?
Thanks

Comment: and do I have to run it every time I add new products to category or it will add the custom options to the new products automatically?