# How to Add customization option for each product in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

So I have multiple products, which can be customized by the user for some extra fee. Like say add a message for 5$. Gift wrap it for 10 $. These options I want on products page. Now I don't want to add these custom option for each products as it will take a lot of time and I have over 500 products. So is there an easy way to do it, where I can select which products can be customized.

The customization option that I want is exactly like this.

http://www.utsavfashion.in/lehenga/deep-purple-viscose-lehenga-choli-with-dupatta/sllwk419-itemcode

But I don't think this is built on Magento. How can I achieve this in Magento.

Answer (score 1):

You can create options programmaticaly

Following this piece of code:

```
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$option = array(
    'title' => 'Your custom option title',
    'type' => 'radio', // could be drop_down ,checkbox , multiple
    'is_require' => 1,
    'sort_order' => 0,
    'values' => getOptions()
    );

function getOptions(){
   return array(
   array(
    'title' => 'Option Value 1',
    'price' =>100,
    'price_type' => 'fixed',
    'sku' => 'any sku for 1',
    'sort_order' => '1'
    ),
array(
    'title' => 'Option Value 2',
    'price' =>100,
    'price_type' => 'fixed',
    'sku' => 'any sku for 2',
    'sort_order' => '1'
    ),
  array(
    'title' => 'Option Value 3',
    'price' =>100,
    'price_type' => 'fixed',
    'sku' => 'any sku for 3',
    'sort_order' => '1'
    )
);
}

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach($products as $product) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
    $product->setProductOptions(array($option));
    $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
    //Do not forget to save the product
    $product->save();

}
```

Comment: Thanks. There is a problem, the options are getting copied 3 times to the product. Basically, each product now has 3 copies of Your custom option title'. Any suggestions ?

Comment: You can debug with xDebug to see why the options are getting copied 3 times. Also you can check if product already has the options.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to have custom options, not configurable products.

And you can mass copy custom options from one product to, say, 100 other product using som mass product actions plugin from magento connect.

Also there are custom options templates extensions.

Also you can generate custom options with some script, see the answer below.

Answer (score -1):

Your best option is likely going to be [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/), which allows you to automate product imports with a variety of options. One of the plugins that comes with it is the [Configurable Item Processor](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Configurable_Item_processor) which allows you to create configurable products based on existing products or attributes.

There will still be some manual work in order to make your products Magmi-friendly. Hopefully this is enough to get you started. If you need help setting up and importing with Magmi, thats probably best for another question.

Comment: He is asking for custom options, not configurable products. Additionally, using something like Magmi for such a task seems like a big overkill.