# Add multiple options to a product

Tags: configurable-product, custom-options

I need to add some options to specific products where a user can select multiple (or none) of them. I found this solution: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/32026/22936

Well, the solution looks okay to me but I need different prices even if the description of the options remains the same. Is there an easy way to achieve this or do I have to create an option for every single price I'll have?

The best thing would be to set the price on the products admin page. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Have you know admin side Custom Options per products?

Comment: Your are manage Custom Options with multiple option from admin end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom option for the product. you can add different prices for different options, also you can set required options for that option type.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It can be so easy. We have a german installation of magento and it seems to be translated with google translate. So the title of the menu point makes absolutely no sense in german.